# Socket closing problem - last portion of data is lost

Tags: java, http, sockets

I have a Java program that accepts connections, receives HTTP requests and sends HTTP replies and some data stored in file (this is a part of caching proxy). Removing everything irrelevant, my code looks like this:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int len = 0;
while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
}
outputStream.flush();
socket.close();
```

This code is executed in particular thread for each connected client.

When I deal with small files (.htm, .gif, .swf, etc.), everything works fine (however, I don't see anything wrong in browser). But when I download large files (.iso), especially several files simultaneously, when system is under load, sometimes I get really strange behavior. Browser downloads 99.99% of a file and when there are less than BUFFER_SIZE of undownloaded bytes, downloading stops for a few seconds and then browser says that error has occured. I can not understand what happens, because **all** data is successfully read and even **all** data is successfully written to outputStream. As you can see, I even do flush(), but it takes no result.

Can anyone explain me what happens?

**EDIT**
Uploaded project to filehosting.org.
[Download source files](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/87679/Proxy.zip). There is zip archive with source code, Build.xml and Readme.txt. Use ant to build solution. Described problem occurs in ClientManager.java, you'll find a comment there.

Comment: Maybe we DO need to see something irrelevant.

Comment: To say the truth, I've only removed logging and inlined method calls.

Comment: Are you setting a `Content-Length` in your HTTP response headers? If so, what are you setting it to?

Comment: Yes, I am. I store headers received from remote server and later load them and send to a client.

Comment: Fire up wireshark on both client and/or server and see if the final bytes are on the wire.  That'll at least let you know if Java's letting them into the socket.

Comment: Wireshark shows that all data is sent. Then proxy sends FIN, browser sends RST.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you should have a problem unless it is poor code at the receiving end, but you should be closing the stream, not the socket, and flush before close is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick trawl through the JDK 1.6 codebase:

- `socket.getOutputStream()` returns a `SocketOutputStream` instance
- `flush()` indeed has no effect on a `SocketOutputStream` instance
- `write()` on a `SocketOutputStream` instance does not seem to buffer anything in Java code
- `shutdownOutput()` should ensure that any outstanding data is written before shutting down the output side of the socket.  At least, the comments say that.

However, some of the Socket etc implementation is native methods, and I didn't delve into that.

Based on what I could tell, the "correct" sequence would be:

```
socket.shutdownOutput();
socket.close();
```

However, you say you've tried that.  Is it possible that the application at the other end is closing the TCP/IP connection early?

Another thought: you tried `setSoLinger(true, 60000)`, but 60000 seconds is possibly longer that the OS allows.  Try `setSoLinger(true, 60)`, and try doing it before you open the output stream.

Comment: I had the same problem before. I never tried shutdownOutput. I would bet 5 bucks it will solve his problem. What I did try at the time was to send something back when the message was fully received - it was part of the protocol, so it was no biggie.

Comment: I think that the OP is using HTTP and therefore doesn't have the option of adding another message.

Comment: I swear it doesn't work. Ok, I'll try to share all my source files today,maybe someone will reproduce a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that would happen, I don't see a problem with your code.  Have you tried using a `BufferedInputStream` to enclose the `FileInputStream`?

Comment: Problem is not in FileInputStream, I get the same problem if data source is not a file, but it's harder to reproduce. Also debug shows that all data is successfully read from file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most probable cause is that you closed the connection without waiting for the data to be fully transmitted.

You can ask Java to wait a little while for you,

```
socket.setOption(SocketOptions.SO_LINGER, new Integer(60));
```

Comment: Tried socket.setSoLinger(true, 60000); No effect.

Comment: This will only delay the application. It has no effect on whether or not the pending data is transmitted. It is.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to sending the length first, and then waiting until I get that data, but if you can't do that, this blog should be helpful:

http://vadmyst.blogspot.com/2008/04/proper-way-to-close-tcp-socket.html

This is for .NET, but the basic logic should be the same.

Once you have sent the data, you will need to have the sending side close their connection, then do `shutdownOutput` and have the other side continue to read until there is a situation where nothing can be read, or an exception is thrown, and then you should have everything.