# Are there any constraints on closing sockets in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets

Could I close the sending (TCP) socket whenever I want?

Are there any cases to avoid using `close(socket_name)`?

Comment: What socket library are you using?

Comment: Not always. The police might be behind you. On a serious not you can close a socket whenever you want. The OS tidies up the mess if any

Comment: #include <sys/socket.h>

Comment: @EdHeal :D But I am not sure you are right.

Comment: The OS looks out for itself. So does the network. It will do its best to sent the data

Comment: As for close() man page: close() returns error if "The close() call was interrupted by a signal;"

Comment: If we´re talking about tidying up mess, that is something the OS will do. But sadly this doesn´t include a guarantee that all sent data got through to the receiving program. There are enough examples in the web (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911645/socket-closing-problem-last-portion-of-data-is-lost, and I experienced it myself too). Something to read: http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable (and read it past the title. SO_LINGER is not the simple and safe solution)

Comment: I'm not aware that fiddling about with `SO_LINGER` is the solution to anything, and I've been staring at it for over 20 years. The [blog](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable) is drivel. It applies to closing the socket when there is unread pending data, not to this situation, or the situtation it describes itself.

Comment: Indeed @EJP, I am waiting your comment on SO_LINGER, because we already discussed a similar concept before from my old account

Comment: @EJP I think you didn´t read even my comment carefully enough. I explicitely stated that SO_LINGER is not the solution, and the linked blog says the same thing. And what is "this" situation here? The main question was "Are there any constraints on closing sockets in C++?" and I replied that closing itself will work anytime, but that could mean data loss. And about the "drivel"... do you have something more reliable with more justification than "didn´t happen in 20 years, so it must be right"?

Comment: I'm commenting on the words you posted here. If it isn't the solution, why mention it? And why await my comment on SO_LINGER when I've already given it? What you actually are asking remains obscure.

Comment: @EJP `I'm commenting on the words you posted here. If it isn't the solution, why mention it?` Because it´s in the title, and in my expierence too many people stop reading in situations like this because they think that´s all to know from an article

Comment: @deviantfan, your comment helps me. Thank you

Comment: As well, every comment would help me to clarify the idea.

Comment: @deviantfan It's in the title of what? An article you introduced yourself? Whose relevance is what?

Comment: @EJP I don´t get if and how we did talk past each other, but I´ve no idea how to write it more clearly (I´ve no idea how it can be misunderstood in the first way). Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could I close the sending (TCP) socket whenever I want?

Yes, subject to below.

> Are there any cases to avoid using close(socket_name)?

Yes. You shouldn't close when you are concurrently blocked in an operation on that socket, e.g. `recv(), send(), select()`, unless the surrounding code is written so as to handle `EBADF` correctly.